# Show that $n! < (n/2)^n$ for all large enough $n$ in as elementary a way as possible

Tags: inequality, factorial

Show  that $n! < (n/2)^n$ for large enough $n$
in as elementary a way as possible.
Using Stirling's formula
is not allowed.

Of, course,
what is true,
is that
$n! < (n/c)^n$
for any $c < e$
for large enough $n$.
But this is simpler.
For extra credit,
determine explicitly
$n(c)$ such that
$n! < (n/c)^n$
for $n > n(c)$.

My answer:

Suppose that
$n! < (n/2)^n$.
Then
$(n+1)!
=n!(n+1)
<(n/2)^n(n+1)
$.
So,
we want
$(n/2)^n(n+1)
<((n+1)/2)^{n+1}
$
or
$2n^n(n+1)
<(n+1)^{n+1}
$
or
$(1+1/n)^n
> 2
$.

By Bernoulli's inequality
($(1+x)^n > 1+nx$
for
$n \ge 2$ 
and
$x > 0$),
$(1+1/n)^n
> 1+n/n
=2
$
for $n \ge 2$.

Therefore the induction step
will work for
$n \ge 2$.
We therefore
have to find an $n$
for which
$n! < (n/2)^n$.

The following table
shows that this is true
for $n=6$.
Therefore
$n! < (n/2)^n$
for
$n \ge 6$.

$\begin{array}{lll}
n & n! & (n/2)^n\\
2 & 2 & 1\\
4 & 24 & 16\\
6 & 720 & 729\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favorite way is to exploit:
$$ n = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right) $$
in order to have:
$$ n! = \prod_{m=2}^{n}\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)=\frac{n^n}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k}=\frac{n^{n+1}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k+1}}\leq\frac{n^{n+1}}{e^{n-1}}$$
so we just need to prove that for any $n$ big enough:
$$\frac{en}{e^{n}}\leq\frac{1}{2^n}$$
that is quite trivial since $e>2$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider sequence $a_n=\frac{n!}{(n/2)^n}=\frac{n!2^n}{n^n}$. Now we have $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)!2^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\frac{n^n}{n!2^n}=\frac{2\cdot n!2^n}{(n+1)^n}\frac{n^n}{n!2^n}=\frac{2}{(\frac{n+1}{n})^n}=\frac{2}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}\rightarrow \frac{2}{e}<1$, from which it follows that $a_n\rightarrow 0$ and thus is less than $1$ from some point on.